# Given string filter out unique element from string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this `String` and I want to filter the digit that came after the big number with the space, so in this case I want to filter out 2 and 0.32. I used this regex below which only filters out decimal numbers, however I want to filter both decimals and integer numbers, is there any way?

```
String s = "ABB123,ABPP,ADFG0/AA/BHJ.S,392483492389 2,BBBB,YUIO,BUYGH/AA/BHJ.S,3232489880 0.32"
```

regex = .AA/BHJ.S,\d+ (\d+.?\d+)

https://regex101.com/r/ZqHDQ8/1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `\d+.?\d+` matches at least two digits. `\d+` matches one or more digits, then `.?` matches any optional char other than line break char, and then again `\d+` matches (requires) at least one digit (it matches one or more).

Also, note that all literal dots must be escaped.

You can use

```
.AA/BHJ\.S,\d+\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/96BB5S/1).

*Details*:

- `.` - any one char
- `AA/BHJ\.S,` - a `AA/BHJ.S,` string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits, and then an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

You could look for anything following `/AA/BHJ` with a reluctant quantifier, then use a capturing group to look for either digits or one or more digits followed by a decimal separator and other digits.

```
/AA/BHJ.*?\s+(\d+\.\d+|\d+)
```

Here is a link to test the regex:

https://regex101.com/r/l5nMrD/1